# How to use DansGuardian as a whitelist?

Tags: internet, privoxy, dansguardian

Set up privoxy and DansGuardian. Followed [THIS](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/web-content-filtering-made-easy/) guide for the main setup, and [THIS](http://contentfilter.futuragts.com/wiki/doku.php?id=configuration_examples) to see how whitelisting can be done.

In the bannedsitelist file I set a blanket block (using **). Then in the exceptionsitelist I added a few sites to test with, and put them like so, at the end of the file:

```
bbc.co.uk
google.com
*gov.uk
```

(last one I was going to test if wildcards work - not seen anything saying if they do or not).

But when I navigate to any of the sites (on the exception list or not) they're all blocked by the blanket block.

What've I done wrong?

Comment: Dansguardian is no longer maintained, and is probably no longer very reliable. You should probably be using e2guardian instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the exceptionsitelist file, move the sites you're whitelisting upwards, under the first set of comments - above the time limiting options.

[Here's a pastebin for an example.](http://www.pastebin.com/n4ixAp7u)

Comment: It *is* a correct answer, but could you please [edit] it and copy-paste some of the OP's (Original Poster) question into it thus making your answer an *excellent* answer in just 2 minutes?
Please drop me a note @Fabby after you've done so to revoke the negative reputation points.

Comment: @Fabby Done! I hope that's good enough - I'm not able to give an example of location as I currently don't have an installation, or a means to install one.

Comment: Upvoted already, *but* the day you have an install, come back and improve it even further!  :P  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby I'm waiting for some stuff to finish at work and I've got 30 minutes spare, so I'll quickly whip up a VM and make a pastebin :P